# Link in alert dialog fragment

Tags: android

I'm using this code to show a simple dialog with a link:

```
  String msg = "http://www.google.com"
  final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(msg);
  Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
  Fragment dialogFrag = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(title, msg);
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(dialogFrag, key).commit();
```

The MyDialogFragment class:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
    MyDialogFragment frag = new MyDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putString("msg", message);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    String msg = getArguments().getString("msg");

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .create();
}
}
```

The dialog doesn't show the hyperlink. I'm using android 5.0.1 without support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Build a `TextView` containing your message as a `SpannableString`:

```
String title = getArguments().getString("title");
String msg = getArguments().getString("msg");

final TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
final SpannableString spannableMsg = new SpannableString(msg);

Linkify.addLinks(spannableMsg, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

textView.setText(spannableMsg);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and add the `TextView` instead of assigning the text:

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle(title)
        .setView(textView)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the time progressed, adding some updated inputs to the query.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   setupView(view)
}    
    
private fun setupView(view: View) {
   toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener({ v -> dismiss() })
   toolbar.title = "New Message"
   view.tvTitle.text = arguments?.getString("title")
   view.tvBody.autoLinkMask = Linkify.ALL
   view.tvBody.text = arguments?.getString("body")
   view.tvBody.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
}
```

Most important 2 steps are:

1. To Linkify
2. setMovementMethod

After this all links will work fine.